# When I'm signed into Facebook Chat on my phone, what's my status look like on the site?

Tags: messaging, facebook

When signed into Facebook Chat in the Messaging Hub, I often wonder if it looks like I'm always lurking on FB.

What does my status look like on the site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will appear as logged in on Facebook Chat, depending on your and their client there might or might not be an icon of a phone at the end for your friends to see:

[image]

Thus, some people might see you as just being online while others might see that you are using a mobile device (which doesn't scream *I'm here* like the Green Bullet does). You can't suppose every client to let Facebook know it is Mobile and nor can you suppose everyone to use Facebook itself for chatting.

So, if you set yourself to be visible / online every time your phone is unlocked you will be available for chat on all services you subscribed to. Take into account a small bit of connection time from the moment you unlock the phone though.

Yes, it looks like you are lurking on FB if you use your Windows Phone a lot...

---

Unrelated, if you put a status message somwhere it will look like this:

```
     _____
    |     | Your Name
    | You | Month Day via Windows Phone
    |_____|

    Your message

    -----------------------------------------------------------
    Actions  Likes / Comments / Shares  About time ago  Privacy
```

Note the `via Windows Phone` part behind the date.

Comment: I don't think you need to have the phone 'unlocked', as a couple of my Facebook friends have said that I seem to be online nearly all the time. I haven't got around to testing it for myself though.

Comment: I think the phone icon only happen when you accept receive messages by sms.

Comment: @paradroid: It could be that 3G keeps you online, but I don't have 3G always enabled which is why that happens. YMMV... :)

Comment: @VitorCanova: Asked those with the phone icon, none of them are using the SMS messaging feature.